# SilverStripe Tab Customization

Tags: tabs, content-management-system, silverstripe

In SilverStripe's CMS I want to remove the `Content` tab within a page. I can do this as follows:

```
$fields->removeFieldsFromTab('Root.Content.Main', 'Content');
```

I then want to create my own custom tab:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.MyTab', $myField);
```

However by adding my own custom tab it brings the `Content` tab back.

The other option is just to make `MyTab` the default 'up' tab. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

### SilverStripe 2.4

To remove the `Content` tab in SilverStripe 2.4:

```
$fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Content', 'Main');
```

And to add a field to a tab named `MyTab`:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.MyTab', $myField);
```

### SilverStripe 3.1

To remove the `Content` tab in SilverStripe 3.1:

```
$fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root', 'Main');
```

And to add a field to a tab named `MyTab`:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.MyTab', $myField);
```

### Notes

Removing the `Content` tab means you cannot control the page title.

[`removeFieldsFromTab`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-FieldList.html#156-170) removes a number of fields from a `Tab`/`TabSet` within this `FieldList`. It takes an array of field names as the second parameter.

[`removeFieldFromTab`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-FieldList.html#142-154) removes a single field from a `Tab`/`TabSet` within this `FieldList`. It takes a string field name as the second parameter.

In your case you want to use `removeFieldFromTab` not `removeFieldsFromTab`.

Comment: Thanks... when I use $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'Content'); it removes the 'content' wysiwyg text editor not the Content tab. Also when I $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.MyTab', $myField); it doesn't add a new tab!

Comment: `addFieldToTab` should create a new tab if it doesn't exist unless the path is wrong, or you could also try `fieldByName('Root')->addFieldToTab('NewTab', $myField)`. Try `removeFieldFromTab('Root', 'Main')` to remove the content tab.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to remove the Content field, not the Content tab. I have updated my answer to remove the Content tab as @colymba suggested (thanks for that). I have also added in code for Silverstripe 2.4, in case this is the version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I  had same problem and I've figured it out.

In getCMSFields() method I wrote

```
$fields = parent::getCMSFields();
$fields->removeByName('XXX'); //this line removes tab
return $fields;
```

where 'XXX' is name of my tab 'Root.XXX'

I hope it'll help someone.